# Laravel 5.3 logging in after auto logout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

After a user is auto logged out and they attempt to log back in again they are bypassing my redirect and ending up on the page they were previously on.

In LoginController.php

```
protected $redirectTo = '/configurepermissions';
```

Users log in and are redirected to a page that gets all their permissions. It works correctly if you either intentionally logout or close your browser, as once you log in again it hits this page, gets permissions and then redirects you to the dashboard from there.

When your login times out, it takes you to the login screen. Once you log back in you end up back on the previous page, but none of your permissions are set.

How do I make sure that my permissions handler always gets called after login, whether it was a user logout or a timeout?

Comment: The handler should be called on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to redirect to that page only to configure permissions.

You can add a listener:

```
$events->listen('Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login', function (array $data) {
    // And call your permissions function here
});
```

Or add a listener to

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\Permissions',
    ],
];
```

As you can see in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#framework-events